# Async function in express middleware: unhandledRejection - response is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await, middleware

I keep getting the error :
**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): ReferenceError: response is not defined**

I have an express middleware like this (simplified):

```
 const myMiddleware = require('./mymiddleware');
 router.use(myMiddleware);
```

Then in the file ./mymiddleware.js

```
module.exports = setup;

function setup(req, res, next) {
  try {
    execute()
      .then(data => {
        req.host = data;
        console.log(data);
        next();
      })
      .catch(() => {});
  } catch (e) { next('error') }
}

async function execute() {
  try {
    const host = getHost();
    ......
    return host;

  } catch (e) {
    return new Error("x");
  }
}
```

I want the async function to handle some promises with the **await** feature.
I see the then / console.log(data) being called but then the error as mentioned is triggered.

can async functions be used with express middleware?

Regards,
Bert

Answer (score 3):

You have made a typo in second line you have written `mymiddleware` instead of writing `myMiddleware`.

Incorrect code

```
 const myMiddleware = require('./mymiddleware');<br>
 router.use(mymiddleware);
```

correct code

```
 const myMiddleware = require('./mymiddleware');<br>
 router.use(myMiddleware);
```

Comment: Thanks. Changed it but the code is just some simplified example code.

Comment: @BertDeterd if it worked ,then plz upvote the answer

Answer (score 0):

I installed a previous version of node.js ( 8.9.0 > 7.6.0 ).

I can install the package now.

When a new release of @sap/xssec comes out I will update the node version and see if it is fixed